# Chrome Incognito Window with 50+ tabs turned black, I cannot close the window because of my tabs. How do i restart only rendering w/o closing Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, crash, window, browser-tabs, rendering

The issue was described here more than 3 years ago: **https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9461262?hl=en**

It seems this issue has never been fixed. I was playing a YouTube video on one of my incognito tabs when the whole window turned completely black. This happened to me twice before already on an incognito window, so I was not thoroughly surprised. When I hover over the tab bar, it still shows the grey box with the tab name, using shortcuts to open or close a tab still works, and basically only the rendering is broken. How do I "restart" my Chrome window's rendering without restarting the process itself? It has happened automatically before when my WebGL crashed and after a few days it automatically restarts itself and is back again. I really cannot afford to lose my incognito tabs or the application storage inside them (cookies, localstorage, indexedDB, etc.)

My chrome version is latest one. I'm using standard build. Tabs from the broken window can still be accessed via another incognito window's tab dropdown menu.

EDIT: My computer randomly froze and black-screened for a few seconds, and then poof, my incognito chrome window was fixed again. This PROVES that this issue can be fixed without restarting or closing chrome. Still though, I need to find out how to fix this issue manually, without relying on nick-of-the-time freezes

Comment: I realize this isn't helpful right now, but if you have 50 invaluable tabs in an incognito window then something's wrong with your workflow.

Comment: @gronostaj It's not my fault, life's circumstances led me here.

Comment: the solution may be dependent on the OS that you are using

Comment: `This PROVES that this issue can be fixed without restarting or closing chrome` ... how do you know that the issue is fixed? ... the black screen is probably just a symptom of an underlying problem

Comment: Try entering `chrome://gpuclean` into omnibox?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me several times as well; different things can cause or fix it at different times and sometimes you just have to give up. Around 20% of the time (the most reliable fix I've found), restarting file explorer fixes it - you can do this by opening file explorer (win+e), and opening task manager (ctrl+shft+esc), then in task manager you can sort by name, select "Windows Explorer" and hit the restart button in the right corner (top right for win11, bottom right for win10).

Another thing you can try is hovering over chrome in the taskbar and right clicking the window you want to rescue [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZpk1.png) and selecting "bookmark all tabs." If your screen is black, it will look like nothing has happened, but chrome will still open the dialog box to bookmark your tabs, so if you type a name you will remember, and then hit enter, you should be able to find it somewhere in your bookmarks folder the next time you open chrome. If you do not get that context menu when you right click, sometimes it will come back if you change focus to the window you want to save and press F5, shft+F5, or ctrl+shft+F5 and then try again (each one is a progressively harder refresh, I think). If want to make sure it worked, you can do the same thing but click rename window instead of bookmark all tabs, again typing a string you will remember and hitting enter, and then checking back to see if the window has a new name